# Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

> Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior

This warning appear just once. I alloc the `UIAlertView` in a base:

```
viewController's viewDidLoad`self.alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle.....`,
```

and

```
 `- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    self.alertView = nil;
}`
```

viewController A and viewController B inherit from the base viewController.

When this viewController A push to a viewController B the warning appear but B pop to A and A push to B again ,this warning doesn't appear.

When I use the simulator (iOS 9.2), the warning appears, but when I use an iPhone (iOS 8.2), it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't alloc init the alertView in viewDidLoad, alloc the alertView when you use it;

Answer (score 0):

It's no need to dealloc properties in ARC.If you have some particular needs,please do this in `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: the best place for deallocation cleanup is -(void)dealloc() method which is called automatically when the object is deallocating. When view is disappeared it doesn't mean it is deallocated. For example view can be disappeared on push segue from it but it will still exist as object.

Comment: @AlexeyLobanov I said "particular needs",dealloc won't call when you push a new view controller.

Comment: yes view (not view but viewController and view as it's property) will not be deallocated on push because the UI needs a view to return back on rewind ;) But in some cases it can be necessary to make cleanup on ARC dealloc and the guarantee place to make it is -(void)dealloc()

Answer (score 0):

if i right understand You define alert in Base class and need to show it only in A:Base but not in B:Base. if so here is code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated];
    if ([self isKindOfClass[A class]]) {
        [self presentViewController:self.alert animated:YES completion:nil]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: this alertView just for display error info .For example A need display network error,and i don't want the alertView display when A  has pushed to B.  And if i delete the self.alterview = nil; the warning is same as before.

Comment: 1) Check what class is now current A or B by: if ([self isKindOfClass[A class]]) in addition to you other error conditions before showing the alert or that You are not in B if (![self isKindOfClass[B class]]) 2) do not delete alert by assign it to nil in viewDidDisappear